# How to adjust brightness and contrast of an image by GPUImage?

Tags: ios, gpuimage

I wrote a method to filter an image with brightness factor and contrast factor as following:

```
- (UIImage*)image:(UIImage*)image withBrightness:(float)brightness contrast:(float)contrast{
    GPUImagePicture *imagePicture = [[GPUImagePicture alloc] initWithImage:image];
    GPUImageBrightnessFilter *brightnessFilter = [[GPUImageBrightnessFilter alloc] init];
    GPUImageContrastFilter *contrastFilter = [[GPUImageContrastFilter alloc] init];

    [imagePicture addTarget:brightnessFilter];
    [brightnessFilter addTarget:contrastFilter];

    brightnessFilter.brightness = brightness; // set brightness
    contrastFilter.contrast = contrast;       // set contrast

    [imagePicture processImage];
    UIImage *filteredImage = [contrastFilter imageFromCurrentlyProcessedOutput];
    return filteredImage;
}
```

Invoke this implementation would raise an error: `<Error>: CGContextDrawImage: invalid context 0x0`.

How to correctly implement brightness and contrast adjustment using GPUImage?

Comment: That looks correct, although creating a new brightness and contrast filter every time you need an image processed is going to introduce some overhead. For realtime operation, I also wouldn't recommend passing through UIImage on the way in and out, either (I'd use a GPUImageView for a live preview), but I don't know the rest of your needs here. Is this with the latest code from the repository? Which method is triggering the CGContextDrawImage error, the GPUImagePicture allocation or the extraction of the image at the end?

Comment: Thanks @BradLarson and your awesome library! I found the image parameter was null, so it raised the error.

Answer (score 0):

You Probably should create a group filter,Check this sample code

```
    GPUImageFilterGroup *groupFilter = [[GPUImageFilterGroup alloc]init];
    [groupFilter addTarget:edit.currentFilter];

    //create a brightness filter
    GPUImageBrightnessFilter *brightnessFilter = [[GPUImageBrightnessFilter alloc]init];
    [brightnessFilter setBrightness:brightnessValue];

    //create a contrast filter
    GPUImageContrastFilter *contrastFilter = [[GPUImageContrastFilter alloc]init];
    [contrastFilter setContrast:contrastValue];

    //create a exposure filter
    GPUImageExposureFilter *exposureFilter =[[GPUImageExposureFilter alloc]init];
    [exposureFilter setExposure:exposureValue];

    //add brightness,contrast,exposure filters to group filter
    [groupFilter addFilter:brightnessFilter];
    [groupFilter addFilter:contrastFilter];
    [groupFilter addFilter:exposureFilter];


    [edit.currentFilter addTarget:brightnessFilter];
    [brightnessFilter addTarget: contrastFilter];
    [contrastFilter addTarget: exposureFilter];
    //setting initial and terminal filters
    [(GPUImageFilterGroup *) groupFilter setInitialFilters:[NSArray arrayWithObject:edit.currentFilter]];
    [(GPUImageFilterGroup *) groupFilter setTerminalFilter:exposureFilter];


    //apply it to the GPUImagePicture
```

Comment: Thanks. But, what is `edit.currentFilter` and what if I don't have one?

Comment: I still got `<Error>: CGContextDrawImage: invalid context 0x0`. [This is my new code](http://codepad.org/Cw5Zfdk7) using group filter. Did I do wrong?

Comment: currentFilter is a property and edit is weak reference of the same class

@property(nonatomic,strong) GPUImageOutput<GPUImageInput> *currentFilter;
__weak EditViewController *edit=self;

Comment: You should add breakpoints and find out which line it is crashing