# How can I increase/decrease the brightness of the image in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, image, uiimage

I've an image , I want to increase/decrease its brightness by using a UISlider? How can I do it?
Is there any default method are available for this? If yes, please tell me..

Thanks!

Comment: You can put a generic UIView in front of the image and set the background color to black with an initial alpha of 0. By using the slider to control the alpha value, you can change the perceived brightness of the image.

Comment: @user3386109 that would only inc/dec contrast effect and not brightness of image.

Comment: Here's a [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19134112/how-to-adjust-brightness-and-contrast-of-an-image-by-gpuimage) will help you out. vote up also @user3655029

Answer (score -2, accepted):

If you don't want to use the link and want to code a custom solution try this:

- In your Storyboard add an imageView with the image
- Add a view that has a white background color
- Add a view with a black background color
- Add a slider and make sure they aren't in each others views!

[image: Storyboard2]

[image]

- Now use CNTRL + click to create your properties in the .M file

[image: properties]

- Create the method for the slider by CNTRL + clicking below the viewDidLoad method and name the method something like sliderChanged:

[image: slidermethod]

- Change (id)sender to (UISlider *)sender
- Last thing to do, fill the method body with this!

[image: methodboadyslider]

these are screenshots from the custom brightness app you just made:

[image: darkness]

[image: bright]

Comment: this will not stored increased/decreased brightness image...u are just playing with view's alpha value, this will have no effect on image. Sorry.